# i have facing problem with editMessageText

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

Message is sending but the bot is not editing the message, what's wrong here ?

here's my code :-

```
if($text == "/hi"){
bot('sendChatAction',[
'chat_id'=>$chat_id,
'action'=>"typing",
]);
bot('sendMessage',[
'chat_id'=>$chat_id,
'text'=>"wait",
'reply_to_message_id'=>$message->message_id,
]);
bot('editMessageText',[
'chat_id'=>$chat_id,
'text'=>"hello",
'reply_to_message_id'=>$message->message_id,
]);
}
```

any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout [editMessageText](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api/#editmessagetext) in Telegram Bot API documentations.

You need to pass `message_id` or `inline_message_id` to specify which message you want to edit.